# Why is ISO 8859-1 embedded into unicode Python strings?

Tags: python, unicode, utf, iso-8859-1

So I have a CSV file.

When I run `file --mime-encoding file.csv`  it says that it uses UTF-8.

But, when I read the file in Python pandas DataFrame and started looking at strings, some of them contain \xa0 (which is non-breaking space in Latin1 (ISO 8859-1)).

This file contains information from different websites.

How is that possible and why are they not displayed as non-breaking space and why were they not encoded properly before being written to a file that appears to be UTF-8?

Comment: Are the other non-ASCII characters in that file properly encoded as UTF-8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is that possible

A file is just a series of bytes. It's entirely possible for a file to contain strings of bytes that are of different encodings.

> why are they not displayed as non-breaking space

Displayed where? They are displayed to you as `\xa0`.

> why were they not encoded properly before being written to a file that appears to be UTF-8?

You don't mention where the CSV comes from so that's impossible to say for sure.

Most likely, your CSV contains data from sources that have different encodings. You may need to guess the encoding for each line in the file rather than the whole file. The `chardet` package can help you guess correct encodings, but it's only a guess.